# A variant "3 jugs problem" requires its general proof of non-existence of its solution.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, graph-theory

Here is a bank interview question:

> You have 3 bottles (or jugs whatever) which have 8, 8 and 3 liters volume. Initially, you have those 2 8-liter bottles filled. Now you are supposed to pour the water equally to 4 people. The poured water cannot return. How to achieve that?

That is to say, initially, I have (8,8,0) for my bottles which have 8, 8, 3 liters volume respectively. Eventually, I would give each of these people 4 liters. I have figured out that there is **NO** such a solution but using the enumeration algorithm which is not beautiful to me. I just wonder whether there is any mathematic-ish solution to this problem. Like [How not to Die Hard with Math](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Oef3MHYEC0), it uses graph theory to do the problem. However, I notice the method is not available to this problem because we do not have the tap.

Comment: if you can return the poured water, you can do it ... though it's not easy... so that's an interesting challenge

Comment: To be more "precise" with the mathematic-ish solution, I mean in general, you have m, n and l liters volume bottles with $l<m, n$ and m, n filled. Given the water to k people evenly with $k|(m+n)$. The water cannot return. When will the solution exist?